# PHP SQL Syntax Error using Bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First, I use a MySQL POO API, there is the important part :

```
public function query($query,$params = null,$fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $query = trim($query);

    $this->Init($query,$params);

    if (stripos($query, 'select') === 0){
        return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
    }
    elseif (stripos($query, 'insert') === 0 ||  stripos($query, 'update') === 0 || stripos($query, 'delete') === 0) {
        return $this->sQuery->rowCount();   
    }   
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

_

```
This API has a loging and showing Class to save and show the SQL error, there is my error :
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE firstname = ? AND age = ? ?' at line 1
Raw SQL : SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :iduser
```

After this I found the SQL included, there is the function and the code who are using this function :

```
function get_member_informations($id)
{
  global $bdd;

  $dn = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :iduser", array("iduser" => $id));
  $dn[0]['avatar'] = base64_decode($dn[0]['avatar']);
  return $dn;
}
```

And the code who use this function :

```
$profil = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", array("username"=>$username));
$id = $profil[0]['id'];
$profile = get_member_informations($id);
```

I know it's a mysql and php issue, so to check if it was not the $id the cause of the error, i made a print_r on it but all was working as well.
I don't know how to fix this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: The error message shows columns `firstname` and `age`, neither of which are references in your two queries. Also, the ? placeholder before WHERE would be valid syntax only if you had a parameter in a JOIN condition, but your two queries contain no JOINs. Conclusion: the query that caused the error is a third query, not those you show.

Comment: The query segment in your error does not match the raw sql shown in your error output. From the SQL in the error message, it looks like you're trying to use a PDO parameter as the table name, which you cannot do ...

Comment: @dleiftah: a parameter could appear before WHERE if it's in a join expression, for example `A JOIN B ON A.x=B.y AND B.z = ? WHERE ...`

Comment: @BillKarwin ... yes indeed. I immediately went to the simplest use case that explained the error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the second dev working on it.
After checking, the class was reporting the bad Raw SQL, i've fixed that and after checking, it's a :

```
FROM :table
"table"=> $this->table
```

Correcting it, thank to all of you, sorry for incoveniance.
@dleiftah ==> Thanks for the great answers ;)