# Listing with foreach: "Illegal string offset" PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I've got a problem with a function who should list all "tweet".
I don't know why there is an error because I used this code previously (3 months) and it work on my other project.

**I'm using PHP 5.4.12**

There is my code:

```
function getTweet()
{
    global $bdd;

    $tweets = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM tweets");

    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        echo $tweet['content'];
    }
}
```

There is the error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' (line 8)

With a print_r:

> 1Test 1700

```
1 = id
Test 1 = content
7 = my id
0 = retweet
0 = favourite
```

With this code I have only one result (but there is several results):

```
function getTweet()
{
    global $bdd;

    $tweets[] = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM tweets");
    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        echo $tweet['content'];
    }

}
```

With this, I have the type of my vars:

```
<?php 
function getTweet()
{
    global $bdd;

    $tweets = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM tweets");
    echo gettype($tweets);
    // Return "array"

    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
         echo gettype($tweet);
         // Return "integerstringintegerintegerinteger"
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: Do `var_dump($tweets)` and see what output you get

Comment: Try var_dump($tweets) before iterating it.

Comment: just for checking the error try doing this within you loop `print_r($tweet)`;

Comment: If you're using Mysqli, you need to use [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get the results.

Comment: When I make the print_r data display without being separated, i'm using PDO

Comment: @JasonVanMalder Show us the displayed data and edit your question.

Comment: It's done, I think it's an array problem

Comment: `*->query` does not return "data" (in native functions/API), this function is customized?

Answer (score 0):

This may help. It checks to make sure that $tweet['content'] exists first, and if it doesn't, will dump the array keys found in $tweet. This should give you a better understanding of what the data may be doing to trigger these errors.

```
function getTweet()
{
    global $bdd;

    $tweets = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM tweets");

    foreach($tweets as $tweet){
        // For debugging, comment this out when tested:
        if(!is_array($tweet) {
            echo "This is NOT an array: $tweet \n<br />\n";
            continue;
        }
        if(isset($tweet['content'])) {
            echo $tweet['content'];
        }
        // For debugging, comment this out when tested:
        else {
            var_dump(array_keys($tweet));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns me every column of the first one " tweet " by saying that it is not an array

Comment: Then `$bdd->query` is not returning a 2D array.

Comment: Try using `queryAll` perhaps?

Comment: It returns: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem:

`*->query` does not return "data" in native functions/API of PHP

`$bdd->query` is a custom function, therefore can not know what causes the failure if you do not post the code of the function.

But if the code is the same as this question: [PHP SQL Syntax Error using Bind parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816838/php-sql-syntax-error-using-bind-parameters)

```
public function query($query, $params = null, $fetchmode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
{
    $query = trim($query);

    $this->Init($query,$params);

    if (stripos($query, 'select') === 0){
        return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
    }
    elseif (stripos($query, 'insert') === 0 ||  stripos($query, 'update') === 0 || stripos($query, 'delete') === 0) {
        return $this->sQuery->rowCount();
    }   
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

It is likely that at some point you changed the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` with another value.

Try:

```
    ...
    if (stripos($query, 'select') === 0){
        echo 'Mode is ASSOC ', (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC===$fetchmode ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'), '<BR>';//should return TRUE
        return $this->sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
    }
    ...
```

This "test-case" must return `TRUE`, if return `FALSE` is why you changed the value of `$fetchmode`

---

### Tips:

I personally do not know why you are using fetchAll when fetch to your code would be much better

- `fetchAll` brings everything together in one variable only (higher consumption of memory PHP)
- `fetch` requests a line at a time